# How do I obtain/insert dummy zero week and costs in between valid data

Tags: sql, insert

This query is a long shot and has been driving me crazy.
What I want to do is basically insert zero weeks and costs in between the valid weeks and costs in a temp table. See the list below

```
    Practice ID Practice Name   Cost    Week
           1    1 - Practice 1  56.00   18
           1    1 - Practice 1  80.00   18
           1    1 - Practice 1  122.00  18
           1    1 - Practice 1  -80.00  19
           1    1 - Practice 1  80.00   19
           1    1 - Practice 1  80.00   21
           3    3 - Practice 3  80.00   24
           3    3 - Practice 3  18.00   28
           3    3 - Practice 3  50.00   29
           3    3 - Practice 3  18.00   30
           3    3 - Practice 3  18.00   34
           3    3 - Practice 3  18.00   35
           4    4 - Practice 4  36.00   29
           4    4 - Practice 4  299.81  31
           4    4 - Practice 4  54.00   32
           4    4 - Practice 4  132.00  34
           4    4 - Practice 4  314.00  35
           4    4 - Practice 4  18.00   35
           4    4 - Practice 4  501.00  36
           4    4 - Practice 4  342.00  36
           7    7 - Practice 7  28.00   24
           7    7 - Practice 7  56.00   27
           7    7 - Practice 7  40.00   27
```

What I want to do is where there are weeks missing between 1 and 36 for each practice I need to somehow insert zeroed weeks and costs for example

```
    Practice ID Practice Name   Cost    Week
           1    1 - Practice 1  0.00    12
           1    1 - Practice 1  0.00    13
           1    1 - Practice 1  0.00    14
           1    1 - Practice 1  0.00    15
           1    1 - Practice 1  0.00    16
           1    1 - Practice 1  0.00    17
           1    1 - Practice 1  56.00   18
           1    1 - Practice 1  80.00   18
           1    1 - Practice 1  122.00  18
           1    1 - Practice 1  -80.00  19
           1    1 - Practice 1  80.00   19
           1    1 - Practice 1  80.00   21
```

As you can see this might seem easy enough but I'm obtaining the payments above from a number of joins the actual week is from a Time table where the date time from the payment is joined to the date time for the week number. Then where there is a matching payment it returns the payment with the payment date.

I've included a depersonalised version of the Query below.

If there is no payment in the payment table then a week number cannot be returned as there is nothing to join it to. (Hard to explain) I have tried to create a temp table with just the fiscal week numbers then update those where there is a payment, but because there is no fixed number of payments per practice per week I cannot determine how many week entries I would need.

If anyone can help with this they're a life saver as this has been giving me a headache for a day or so now.

```
    SELECT R.[Practice id]
        ,W.[Practice Short Name]
        ,convert(VARCHAR(10), R.[Practice id]) + ' - ' + W.[Practice Short Name] AS         PracticeNumberName
,SUM(R.[Cost]) AS 'Cost'
,I.FiscalWeek
,I.WeekEndingDate
,R.[Owner]
,R.[Description]
    FROM dbo.Payments R
    INNER JOIN dbo.Time I ON convert(VARCHAR(10), R.[AllocationDate], 121) =       convert(VARCHAR(10), I.CalendarDate, 121)
    INNER JOIN dbo.OtherDetails W ON R.[Practice id] = W.[Practice Id]
    WHERE [paymenttype] NOT IN (5,14,15)
AND I.[FiscalYear] in (2013,2014)
AND I.[FiscalWeek] between 1 and 36
AND R.[cost] <> 0
AND R.[Practice id] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
    GROUP BY R.[Practice id]
,W.[Practice Short Name]
,convert(VARCHAR(10), R.[Practice id]) + ' - ' + W.[Practice Short Name]
,I.FiscalWeek
,I.WeekEndingDate
,R.[Owner]
,R.[Description]
     HAVING sum(R.[cost]) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you started.  You can look after the details.

```
select i.FiscalWeek, isnull(somefield, 0) cost
, etc
from time i left join payments r on etc
left join other tables
```

This will give you all the fiscal weeks whether there are matching records in the other tables or not.